# Domain of $y= \ln\lfloor x^2+x+1\rfloor$

Tags: functions

Find the domain of $ y=\ln\lfloor x^2+x+1\rfloor$

My attempt:-

Since $x^2+x+1$ is always positive and also $\lfloor x^2+x+1\rfloor$ must be greater than 0 but $\lfloor x^2+x+1\rfloor$ is negative between $(-1,0)$ so the domain of the given question must be $x\in\mathbb R \setminus(-1,0)$.

Is there any another way to find the domain?

Comment: What is GIF?  ............

Comment: @MariaMazur the greastest integer function

Comment: Greatest integer function

Comment: What does that mean

Comment: Plz go through this https://mathbits.com/MathBits/TISection/PreCalculus/GraphGreatestIntFunction.html

Comment: also known as [floor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html)

Comment: In latex the notation for GIF is `\lfloor x \rfloor` rendering to $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: @MariaMazur The greatest integer function is the function defined on real numbers, that gives for a real number $x$ the greatest integer which is less than or equal to $x$. For example $\lfloor 2.5 \rfloor = 2$, or $\lfloor 4 \rfloor = 4$, or $\lfloor -1,6 \rfloor = -2$. It is a very usual function, you will probably hear about it later in your studies :)

Comment: I think you mean to say that $\lfloor x^2+x+1\rfloor$ is *zero*, not negative, between $-1$ and $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct (except the strange claim for negativity, I think you mistaken with $\ln(x^2+x+1)$), so it is just a matter of redacting it.

I would say that the domain of $\ln$ is $]0,+\infty[$ so we need $\lfloor x^2+x+1 \rfloor >0$ and this is equivalent to being $\ge 1$ since this is an integer.

Since $\lfloor u\rfloor\le u\ $ (and also $u<\lfloor u\rfloor+1$ but this does not interest us at the moment), the latter condition is itself equivalent to $x^2+x+1\ge 1\iff x(x+1)\ge 0$ .

And you conclude like you did that $x\in\mathbb R\setminus(-1,0)$, arguing that a quadratic is positive outside its roots when the dominant coefficient is positive.